# Computing and proving existence of integral

Tags: real-analysis, limits, improper-integrals

We're supposed to prove the existence of the following integral and compute it.

$\int^{10}_{y=0}\int^{\pi/3}_{x=0}{xy \cos x y^2}\,\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y$

My two cents on this. I was trying to use Fubini's theorem and change the order of integration, but ran into trouble evaluating the actual integral itself.

Comment: Looks like a perfectly reasonable approach. I think the $y$-integral should be possible.

Comment: Is it $\cos(xy^2)$ or $\cos(x)y^2$ ?

Comment: It is $cos(x)y^2$

Comment: Are you sure? And if so, you could simplify it: $xy \cos(x) y^2=xy^3 \cos(x)$.

Comment: Oh no, it's the other way around, I misread the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It exist because the integrand is continuous on the compact set $[0,\pi/3]\times [0,10]$. Then you can apply [Fubini's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem) and get
\begin{align}\int^{10}_{y=0}\int^{\pi/3}_{x=0}{xy \cos x y^2}\,\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y&=\int^{\pi/3}_{x=0}\left(\int^{10}_{y=0}{xy \cos x y^2}\,\mathrm{d}y\right)\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int^{\pi/3}_{x=0}\left[\frac{1}{2} \sin (x y^2)\right]^{10}_{y=0}\mathrm{d}x.
\end{align}
Can you take it from here?

Comment: Uhm why did I not thought about that ;) +1 Mate!

Comment: So it would be the integral of 1/2 sin(100x) with respect to x?

Comment: Yes, you are correct!

Answer (score 0):

Well, we know that:

$$\mathscr{I}:=\int_0^{10}\int_0^\frac{\pi}{3}x\cdot\text{y}\cdot\cos\left(x\cdot\text{y}^2\right)\space\text{d}x\space\text{d}\text{y}=$$
$$\int_0^{10}\text{y}\cdot\left\{\int_0^\frac{\pi}{3}x\cdot\cos\left(x\cdot\text{y}^2\right)\space\text{d}x\right\}\space\text{d}\text{y}\tag1$$

Using:

$$\cos\left(x\cdot\text{y}^2\right)=\sum_{\text{n}=0}^\infty\frac{\left(-1\right)^\text{n}}{\left(2\text{n}\right)!}\cdot\left(x\cdot\text{y}^2\right)^{2\text{n}}=$$
$$\sum_{\text{n}=0}^\infty\frac{\left(-1\right)^\text{n}}{\left(2\text{n}\right)!}\cdot x^{2\text{n}}\cdot\text{y}^{4\text{n}}\tag2$$

So, we can write:

$$\mathscr{I}=\int_0^{10}\text{y}\cdot\left\{\int_0^\frac{\pi}{3}x\cdot\left(\sum_{\text{n}=0}^\infty\frac{\left(-1\right)^\text{n}}{\left(2\text{n}\right)!}\cdot x^{2\text{n}}\cdot\text{y}^{4\text{n}}\right)\space\text{d}x\right\}\space\text{d}\text{y}=$$
$$\mathscr{I}=\int_0^{10}\text{y}\cdot\left\{\int_0^\frac{\pi}{3}\sum_{\text{n}=0}^\infty\frac{\left(-1\right)^\text{n}}{\left(2\text{n}\right)!}\cdot x^{1+2\text{n}}\cdot\text{y}^{4\text{n}}\space\text{d}x\right\}\space\text{d}\text{y}=$$
$$\mathscr{I}=\int_0^{10}\text{y}\cdot\sum_{\text{n}=0}^\infty\frac{\left(-1\right)^\text{n}}{\left(2\text{n}\right)!}\cdot\text{y}^{4\text{n}}\cdot\left\{\int_0^\frac{\pi}{3}x^{1+2\text{n}}\space\text{d}x\right\}\space\text{d}\text{y}\tag3$$

Now, using:

$$\int_0^\frac{\pi}{3}x^{1+2\text{n}}\space\text{d}x=\left[\frac{x^{2+2\text{n}}}{2+2\text{n}}\right]_0^\frac{\pi}{3}=\frac{\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)^{2+2\text{n}}}{2+2\text{n}}\tag4$$

So:

$$\mathscr{I}=\int_0^{10}\text{y}\cdot\sum_{\text{n}=0}^\infty\frac{\left(-1\right)^\text{n}}{\left(2\text{n}\right)!}\cdot\text{y}^{4\text{n}}\cdot\left\{\frac{\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)^{2+2\text{n}}}{2+2\text{n}}\right\}\space\text{d}\text{y}=$$
$$\int_0^{10}\sum_{\text{n}=0}^\infty\frac{\left(-1\right)^\text{n}}{\left(2\text{n}\right)!}\cdot\text{y}^{1+4\text{n}}\cdot\left\{\frac{\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)^{2+2\text{n}}}{2+2\text{n}}\right\}\space\text{d}\text{y}=$$
$$\sum_{\text{n}=0}^\infty\frac{\left(-1\right)^\text{n}}{\left(2\text{n}\right)!}\cdot\frac{\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)^{2+2\text{n}}}{2+2\text{n}}\cdot\int_0^{10}\text{y}^{1+4\text{n}}\space\text{d}\text{y}\tag5$$

Now, using:

$$\int_0^{10}\text{y}^{1+4\text{n}}\space\text{d}\text{y}=\left[\frac{\text{y}^{2+4\text{n}}}{2+4\text{n}}\right]_0^{10}=\frac{10^{2+4\text{n}}}{2+4\text{n}}\tag6$$

So:

$$\mathscr{I}=\sum_{\text{n}=0}^\infty\frac{\left(-1\right)^\text{n}}{\left(2\text{n}\right)!}\cdot\frac{\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)^{2+2\text{n}}}{2+2\text{n}}\cdot\frac{10^{2+4\text{n}}}{2+4\text{n}}=\frac{3}{400}\tag7$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm wondering though, how did you finalize the last term? I don't see how you could cancel any of those terms out. Did you just use a calculator?